# while statement with stack in Inorder Traversal

Tags: python, while-loop, stack, tree-traversal

When I want to save all nodes into an inorder list `sorted_node_val`, I use while statement.

```
    def closestKValues(self, root, target, k):
        # write your code here
        stack = []
        sorted_node_val = []
        node = root
        while node:
            stack.append(node)
            node = node.left

        while stack is not None:
            node = stack.pop()
            sorted_node_val.append(node.val)
            if node.right:
                node = node.right
                while node:
                    stack.append(node)
                    node = node.left
```

However the code above yields error with `while stack is not None:` and the result is

```
  File "/Users/Python/901.py", line 35, in closestKValues
    node = stack.pop()

IndexError: pop from empty list
```

I changed while statement into `while stack:` and fixed this error.
But I wonder what's the difference between `while stack is not None:` and `while stack:`

Comment: `stack = []` ==> `stack is not None`, which means that your program goes into the loop and attempts to pop an item from the `stack` array even when it's empty (which is pretty obvious from the error BTW).

Comment: In other words, the value of `stack` doesn't change into `None` after you pop the last element.

Answer (score 0):

At the very end of your stack,  `stack = []`. This is an list of length 0, not a none object. You can verify this by trying `None == []`, which will be `False`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this condition out, by running a Python IDE and creating an empty array. Then, with the empty array, run a condition check:

```
temp = []
temp is None
```

The output is False.

This tells us that an empty array is not considered to be None, which makes sense because an array is not of a null type.